# Many CSV files (workbooks) are generated.I want them as a single CSV file ( under one single workbook in a single sheet).( in web crawling)

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-crawler, export-to-csv

In my code many CSV files are being generated. I want them as a single csv file. The five parties of all years has to be executed under one csv file. Basically I am trying to do web crawling and trying to create a time series of polls for those (CDU, SPD, FDP, GRUNEN, LEFT)parties.

```
  import scrapy
  import re
  import csv


  class VoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = 'VoteSpider'
  start_urls = ['https://www.wahlrecht.de/umfragen/forsa.htm'] 

def __init__(self):  
    self.CDU = {}
    self.SPD = {}  
    self.FDP = {}  
    self.Green = {}  
    self.left = {}  


def parse(self, response):
    regex = r"[forsa]+[\/]+[0-9]+.htm"
    tableBody = response.xpath('//*[@class="wilko"]//tbody')
    hxs = scrapy.Selector(response)
    all_links = hxs.xpath('*//a/@href').extract()
    yearLinks = []
    for link in all_links:
        matches = re.search(regex, link, re.MULTILINE)
        if matches:
            yearLinks.append(link)
    for link in yearLinks:
        newlink = "https://www.wahlrecht.de/umfragen/"+ link
        yield scrapy.Request(url = newlink, callback=self.parseLink, meta={'name':link})
    self.parseTable(tableBody)

def parseTable(self,tableBody):
    CDU= []
    SPD = []
    FDP= []
    Green= []
    left= []

    rows = tableBody.xpath('//tr')
    del rows[:5]
    for row in rows:
        CDU.append(row.xpath('td//text()')[2].extract())
        SPD.append(row.xpath('td//text()')[3].extract())
        Green.append(row.xpath('td//text()')[4].extract())
        FDP.append(row.xpath('td//text()')[5].extract())
        left.append(row.xpath('td//text()')[6].extract())

    with open('CDU'+'Current'+'.csv', 'w') as csvFile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
        writer.writerows(CDU)
    with open('SPD'+'Current'+'.csv', 'w') as csvFile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
        writer.writerows(CDU)
    with open('left'+'Current'+'.csv', 'w') as csvFile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
        writer.writerows(CDU)
    with open('Green'+'Current'+'.csv', 'w') as csvFile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
        writer.writerows(CDU)
    with open('FDP'+'Current'+'.csv', 'w') as csvFile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
        writer.writerows(CDU)

    self.CDU['Current'] = [] 
    self.SPD['Current'] = [] 
    self.Green['Current'] = [] 
    self.FDP['Current'] = [] 
    self.left['Current'] = [] 


    self.CDU['Current'].append(CDU)
    self.SPD['Current'].append(SPD)
    self.Green['Current'].append(Green)
    self.FDP['Current'].append(FDP)
    self.left['Current'].append(left)

def parseLink(self, response):
    CDU= []
    SPD = []
    FDP= []
    Green= []
    left= []  

    name = response.meta.get('name')
    yearNumber = re.findall('\d+',name)[0]
    x = 0
    if yearNumber == '2007':
        x = 4
    elif yearNumber == '1998':
        x = 3
    elif yearNumber == '1999':
        x = 3
    elif yearNumber == '2000':
        x = 3
    elif yearNumber == '2001':
        x = 3
    elif yearNumber == '2002':
        x = 3
    elif yearNumber == '2003':
        x = 3
    elif yearNumber == '2004':
        x = 3
    elif yearNumber == '2005':
        x = 5
    elif yearNumber == '2006':
        x = 3
    elif yearNumber == '2008':
        x = 4
    elif yearNumber ==  '2013':
        x = 4
    tableBody = response.xpath('//*[@class="wilko"]//tbody')
    rows = tableBody.xpath('//tr')
    del rows[:x]
    for row in rows:
        CDU.append(row.xpath('td//text()')[2].extract())
        SPD.append(row.xpath('td//text()')[3].extract())
        Green.append(row.xpath('td//text()')[4].extract())
        # print(row.xpath('td//text()').extract())
        FDP.append(row.xpath('td//text()')[5].extract())
        left.append(row.xpath('td//text()')[6].extract())

    with open('CDU'+yearNumber+'.csv', 'w') as csvFile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
        writer.writerows(CDU)
    with open('SPD'+yearNumber+'.csv', 'w') as csvFile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
        writer.writerows(CDU)
    with open('left'+yearNumber+'.csv', 'w') as csvFile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
        writer.writerows(CDU)
    with open('Green'+yearNumber+'.csv', 'w') as csvFile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
        writer.writerows(CDU)
    with open('FDP'+yearNumber+'.csv', 'w') as csvFile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
        writer.writerows(CDU)

    self.CDU[yearNumber]= [] 
    self.SPD[yearNumber] = [] 
    self.Green[yearNumber] = [] 
    self.FDP[yearNumber] = [] 
    self.left[yearNumber] = [] 

    self.CDU[yearNumber].append(CDU)
    self.SPD[yearNumber].append(SPD)
    self.Green[yearNumber].append(Green)
    self.FDP[yearNumber].append(FDP)
    self.left[yearNumber].append(left)
```

I want the expected output to be as, all CDU, SPD, GRUNEN, FDP, LEFT parties of all years under one CSV file

Comment: CSV files are text files, they don't have separate sheets as you're expecting. I guess you need them as separate sheets in an excel instead?

Comment: Add first few lines of each CSV with some sample data.

Comment: now, I get them as a different workbook. I want them in a single workbook under single sheet

Answer (score 0):

Instead of opening multiple files, you can append to a single file, like so:

```
...

with open('ALL'+yearNumber+'.csv', 'a+') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    writer.writerows(CDU)
    writer.writerows(SPD)
    writer.writerows(left)
    writer.writerows(Green)
    writer.writerows(FDP)

...
```

Comment: is it possible to get under a single workbook and single sheet as well

Comment: This would write everything to a single sheet. Excel has the concept of workbook/sheets, not csv.

Comment: thank you. but the problem again here is..previously I got, CDU 1998 as a separate book, CDU 1999 as a separate workbook, etc., Now, all the parties under 1998 are in a separate workbook and all the aprties under 1999 under separate workbook. if I open 1998, I couldnt able to differentiate which parties percentage is that.  I want to get something like this : CDU 1998 in a column , CDU 1999 in a column, spd 1998 in a column like wise. So that I will be able to create a time series of polls for the 5 parties. I want it under a single workbook and single sheet